# tar.gpg vs tar.gz.gpg

Tags: gpg, gzip

Is it redundant to compress a tar archive before encrypting it using GPG? From my understanding, GPG will compress the file that it encrypts. Is it preferable to do `tar -> gpg` instead of `tar -> gzip -> gpg`?

Answer (score 6):

GnuPG uses ZIP compression by default, which is slightly less performant in many cases than `gzip`. This would suggest that a separate `gzip` phase could be useful, but GnuPG also supports zlib compression, using the same compression algorithms as `gzip`; to select this, specify `--compress-algo zlib`.

You can also specify `bzip2` instead to get better compression, with `--compress-algo bzip2`.

In both cases, the compression “level” can be specified with `-z`, *e.g.* `-z 9`.

PGP only supports ZIP compression, but that’s probably not much of a concern nowadays.

Comment: Please note that the recommended way (recommended by Werner Koch, the author of GnuPG) is to use dedicated tools to do the compression (https://gnupg-users.gnupg.narkive.com/FAkQd03n/using-other-compression-algos-with-gnupg). "The reason why we have compresion algorithms in
OpenPGP are mainly out of tradition. On a Unix system the use of
specialized tools is the way to go; e.g. gpg for encryption and bzip2
for compressing." Dates back 2006, but I think it's still relevant today.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, GPG compresses a file (by default with zip) before encrypting it. Therefore it is useless to compress the file beforehand.
Note that you can use [`gpgtar`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpgtar.html) to encrypt files into an archive, and do everything in only one step.

GPG has the option `--compress-algo name` to define the compression algorithm to use. From the `gpg2` manual:

```
--compress-algo <name>

Use compression algorithm <name> "zlib" is RFC-1950 ZLIB compression. "zip" is 
RFC-1951 ZIP compression which is used by PGP. "bzip2" is a more modern compression
scheme that can compress some things better than zip or zlib, but at the cost of more
memory used during compression and decompression. "uncompressed" or "none" disables 
compression. If this option is not used, the default behavior is to examine the
recipient key preferences to see which algorithms the recipient supports.
If all else fails, ZIP is used for maximum compatibility.

ZLIB may give better compression results than ZIP, as the compression window size is 
not limited to 8k. BZIP2 may give even better compression results than that, but will
use a significantly larger amount of memory while compressing and decompressing. This
may be significant in low memory situations. Note, however, that PGP (all versions) only
supports ZIP compression. Using any algorithm other than ZIP or "none" will make the 
message unreadable with PGP. In general, you do not want to use this option as it 
allows you to violate the OpenPGP standard. --personal-compress-preferences 
is the safe way to accomplish the same thing.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest another point of view: `gzip` have constant length header with static number there which can lead to know part of plain text document before encryption. And this is not recommended.

Tar (AFAIK) do not have global header for the archive so there is not such weakness as above.

So my recommendation is (from security point of view) to use `gpg` on `tar`

Comment: I'm not sure this is impactful in practice. gpg prefixes a significant amount of random data to the stream, and the gzip header is much smaller than a block.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, do not have experience with `gpg` but to know part of plain text and to have it encrypted is not good. And even if this is random data, there should be some information about the size of this random block otherwise decrypt can be a challenge.

Comment: Yes, known-plaintext attacks are a thing, but they were also a thing back when PGP was first designed (not OpenPGP, but _original_ PGP). There are lots of modern cryptography practices that OpenPGP doesn't follow, but we're talking about an attack mechanism that was well understood back in the 80s. Unless you have a pointer to someone publishing an attack taking advantage of this short a segment of plaintext despite those countermeasures...

Comment: PGP doesn't directly encrypt the data you give it; the actual plaintext for the encryption algorithm is a set of nested PGP packets _containing_ the data, with or without compression, and those packets provide about as much known plaintext as the gzip header would. And although tar doesn't have a separate fixed header it also has known content near the beginning. So yes this attack was already dealt with @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, no, as you can't see the list of tar content you do not have such distinguished header as gzip have.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, ...about the pointer to someone exploiting this I asked for. Do you have one? I did a quick google over at [crypto.se], and can't find anything contradicting the assertion that PGP is quite resistant to known-plaintext attacks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, https://www.schneier.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/paper-pgp.pdf

Comment: @RomeoNinov, (1) chosen-ciphertext is not known-plaintext; (2) note the message integrity check foiling their attack -- that's the random data prefixing the message I talked about earlier.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, moreover, the authors of that paper explicitly describe having OpenPGP use zlib under-the-hood as able to defeat their attack, despite (surely!) knowing about the few bytes of header it creates.